# Do I really need kubeadm on a managed cloud cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am fiddling around with Kubernetes on a small managed cluster within AKS.

It looks like I'm ready to go with deploying as my node pools are already provisioned and bootstrapped (or that's what it looks like) upon setup.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I really need kubeadm on a managed cloud cluster?

You DO NOT need `kubeadm` tool when using [Azure AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/#overview) / [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) / [Google GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) managed Kubernetes clusters.

[`kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/) is used to create a self-managed Kubernetes cluster.

> You can use the kubeadm tool to create and manage Kubernetes clusters. It performs the actions necessary to get a minimum viable, secure cluster up and running in a user friendly way.